# Using Windows media center SDK from Builder C++ or Delphi

Tags: delphi, c++builder, windows-media-center

I have an application done already, it shows images, videos, etc. I just want to add support for TV channels, and I want to use windows media center from my program.

I have downloaded the Windows Media Center SDK but i dont know how to instance the classes ... Microsoft.MediaCenter, Microsoft.MediaCenter.Hosting, etc.

Any help would be welcomed, since i'm a bit lost.

The main target is be able to control WMC, run tv tunner and change tv channels programmatically

Comment: http://david.gardiner.net.au/2010/10/writing-media-center-application-in.html

Comment: I checked that page already, that's for WMC plugins if i'm not wrong, what I want is controlling mediacenter from my own app

Comment: @hamboy75 you need to ask a specific question you would like answered.